# Getting/Setting values SharedPreference globaly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hi i have a class (`MyCustomForm.xml`) which i use as a `LoginForm` for the user.
Now i want to save and load the value from the username(`EditText`) from the `LoginForm` using `SharedPreferences` but i do not know how to set the value of username saved by `SharedPreferences` into the `EditText` in `LoginForm(MyCustomForm.xml`).

I was thinking to save the value in `OnPause` in my Main.xml and load the value through `OnCreate` in the class `MyCustomForm.xml`

Generaly i would like to use `SharedPreferences` globaly.

How would this look like?
Can somebody please help me to get on the right track?

It was thinking something like this `Main.xml`:

```
public class AndroidLogin extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override     
protected void onPause() { 
   super.onPause();  
     Editor e = mPrefs.edit();
     e.putString(USERNM, username);
     e.commit();
}
}
```

Code `MyCustomForm (LoginForm`):

```
public class MyCustomForm extends Dialog {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(com.sencide.R.layout.inlogdialog);

    EditText userTest = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    userTest.setText(USERNM);
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YouActivity.this);

String servername = settings.getString("sharedPreferencesKey", "defaultValue");
server.setText(servername);  // EditText
```

And you store data like this :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("server", "serverName");
```

EDIT :

This piece of code should do the trick for you :

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
String servername = settings.getString("sharedPreferencesKey", "defaultValue");
```

Comment: Hi Android-Droid,
Thx for answering, if i do: SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyCustomForm.this);
I get the message The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (MyCustomForm).

Comment: Hi, ok thank you very much.
Last question, is the SharedPreference Private so that it can not be accessed from other applications?

Comment: Yes, only your application can access your application's shared preferences.

Comment: are you there?
I need your help for a minute, can we have a short chat please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Prefs & Editor

```
SharedPreferences spOptions;
SharedPreferences.Editor spOptionEditor;

spOptions = getSharedPreferences("yourKey", 0);
spOptionEditor = spOptions.edit();

string username = spOptions.getString("USERNM", null)
```

null represents the default value if you don't have anything stored yet

You store the data like this:

```
spOptionEditor.putString("USERNM", txtUsername.getText().toString());
spOptionEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Hi richman64,
Thx for answering but how do i pass the value received in main.xml to the class MyCustomForm.xml?
That`s the main question, how would this look like?
Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I would recommend you to save the username on a valid login, and not in any lifecycle method. 
Then change myForm to this:

```
public class MyCustomForm extends Dialog {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(com.sencide.R.layout.inlogdialog);
        String s = getContext().getSharedPreferences("prefName", Mode.PRIVATE).getString(USERNM);
        EditText userTest = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        userTest.setText(s);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
public void sharedPrefernces() {
    sh_Pref = getSharedPreferences("Login Credentials", MODE_PRIVATE);
    toEdit = sh_Pref.edit();
    toEdit.putString("Username", username);
    toEdit.putString("Password", password);
    toEdit.commit();

}
```

Read more: http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-shared-preferences-in-android/28370#ixzz34ymRp6mN

Answer (score 0):

Just create a file called preferences... and store the value to it using different methods.

Use the methods people have suggested to put and get data from them...

```
    public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
          public static final String PREFS_PRIVATE = "PREFS_PRIVATE";
          public static final String MASTERKEY = "!@#$%^&*";

          public static final String KEYA = "KEYA";
          public static final String KEYB = "KEYB";
          public static final String KEYC = "KEYC";

           --- the create and get methods for getting and sharing data in the prefs... ..... 
         public static void createPreference(Context context){

        getPrefs(context).edit().putString(KEYA, "Default");
        getPrefs(context).edit().putInt(KEYB, 0);
        getPrefs(context).edit().putLong(KEYC, 0);
        getPrefs(context).edit().putBoolean(KEYD, false);
        getPrefs(context).edit().commit();

    }

    public static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_PRIVATE, 0);
        }
        public static String getUsername(Context context) {

            getPrefs(context).getString(USERNAME, "default");

        }

    public static void setUsername(Context context, String value) {


            getPrefs(context).edit().putString(USERNAME, value).commit();

    }
}
```

..... so on and so forth.....  Just implement it if you find any doubt or any thing that you need in more specific please let me know.

Comment: Thx medampudi,
I will definitly also have a look at your code.
Should i have any questions, i will get back to you.

Comment: medampudi are you there?
I wanted to try your class, but do not know how to call the getUsername in the dialog.xml and setUsername in the main.xml.

Comment: what exactly is tthe dialog.xml do... this is how i implemented it.. in the main.xml there are two fields username and password that accept values from the user. if and then there is a button in the bottom that says login. now... When i press the button... it goes to a button clicklistener and then the values present in the username and the password are saved for future reference and then vaildated against a condition or a webservice call happens and you execute the necesary things required. and in the future if you donot want to go through the process of login...

Comment: you can check whether it was done previously too... or something. and try to solve it in a different method. i dont understand why you have to call it in the XMLs i dont think you can.... you can call it in the display files... that you use them for... remember setContentView method... those.

Comment: as you have marked an answer i thought that you might have solved it... can you briefly exaplin what worked and where were you stuck at.